# Insert data if table exist or create table and insert data

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, windows-services

I am Trying to Insert data through windows service, I have to check whether the table exist, and Insert data if it exists. If not exist, Create table and insert data in same table...I can Create the table and insert Data if table not exist.But if table exist unable to Insert the data to the table with the below code...Thanks in advance....

```
  if not exists (select * from sysobjects where name='" + tablename + "' and  xtype='U') 

create table " + tablename + 
" (ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,Data nvarchar(max) NULL)  
Insert into " + tablename + " (Data) VALUES('" + Message + "')
```

**Update:** 
  After modifying, it is working fine with sql server but when i try to do this through visual studio Console application its throwing the Exception!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is checking if it does not exist, it creates it and inserts data, but u skipped the else part 
where the table exists, then you only insert data

```
if not exists (select * from sysobjects where name='" + tablename + "' and      xtype='U') 

begin
create table " + tablename + 
" (ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,Data nvarchar(max) NULL)  
Insert into " + tablename + " (Data) VALUES('" + Message + "') 
End

ELSE
  Insert into " + tablename + " (Data) VALUES('" + Message + "')
```

or specify the begin and end of what to do upon this condition

```
if not exists (select * from sysobjects where name='" + tablename + "' and      xtype='U') 

begin
create table " + tablename + 
" (ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,Data nvarchar(max) NULL)  
end 
Insert into " + tablename + " (Data) VALUES('" + Message + "')
```

Comment: I have Tried the code above But Its throwing Syntax error"Invalid Syntax near ELSE"  @Zeina

Comment: Thanks for the Answer Dude But Here It is throwing Exception"There is already an object name" tablename "..@Zeina

Comment: there must be something wrong... since we are not creating the table, unless it does not exist... on my pc it is working fine!! plz recheck ur code

Comment: Yes @Zeina It creates table if not exist but throwing exception if table exists like the above....

Comment: Its working fine with sql server but when i try to do this through visual studio Console application its throwing the Exception.....

Answer (score 0):

For that kind of a problem I would use [GOTO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/goto-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) like this in T-SQL (MS SqlServer):

```
IF EXISTS (select * from sysobjects where name='" + tablename + "' and xtype='U')
     GOTO MakeInsert;
ELSE GOTO CreateTable;

CreateTable:
    CREATE TABLE " + tablename + " (ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,Data nvarchar(max) NULL)
MakeInsert:
    INSERT INTO  " + tablename + " (Data) VALUES('" + Message + "')
```

If table needs to be created then insert will also run but not the other way around.